# CSS backdrop-filter not working as expected

Tags: html, css, filter, webkit

we were successfully able to apply `backdrop-filter` to our navigation bar. But on mobile devices, where the navigation bar is collapsed, we are showing the traditional drop-down navigation menu. When applying the filter to the drop-down menu `div` it's ignoring the blur and simply not showing it. The weird part is that if we switch off the blur on the navigation bar itself, it'll work. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

**Note, the website is live. Please visit [socialkit.com](https://socialkit.com) to investigate further.**

[image]

Comment: Please can we bump this because I have the exact same issue, even that it miraculously works when switching the blur off the header in Chrome's dev tools. The mobile navigation element is nested inside the header so I did also try setting the backdrop-filter of a parent of the mobile nav to 'none' to see if that would help... it didn't. Mine is a Wordpress site if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in Chrome, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=993971
Check this post, they suggest a workaround [backdrop-filter not working for nested elements in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997948/backdrop-filter-not-working-for-nested-elements-in-chrome)