# CSS Backdrop filter is not working properly for dropdown menu in chrome

Tags: html, css, filter, frontend, web-frontend

I am making a website where I have given backdrop filter property to navbar as well as a dropdown menu. But this blur effect is only working for navbar and not for dropdown menu. But strange thing is that both are working on firefox but on chrome only backdrop filter is working for navbar not for dropdown menu.
CSS for navbar is given

```
.navbar{
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90.39deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.61) 1.19%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100.87%
  );
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* padding: 34px 100px; */
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 20;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}
```

and CSS for dropdown menu is:

```
.navbar #mobileDropdownMenu {
  background: linear-gradient(
    90.39deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.61) 1.19%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100.87%
  );
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:-12px
}
```

[image: navbar]
[image: menu]

I could not find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [well-documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997948/backdrop-filter-not-working-for-nested-elements-in-chrome) that `backdrop-filter` doesn't play nicely with nested elements in Chrome.

You can work around this by removing the blur effect out of your `.navbar` and `.navbar #mobileDropdownMenu` rules, and moving it into CSS pseudo-elements for each of them:

```
.navbar::before, .navbar #mobileDropdownMenu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: @moto Thanks for your response. It worked well for android devices and desktop. But it is not working on IOS device.

Comment: @EhtashamHaider The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) [suggest](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter) that although it's supported on iOS Safari, you'll need to include the `-webkit-` prefix