# backdrop-filter doesn`t work on my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Backdrop-filter: blur(20px); doesnt work ;(

I have a dropdown menu that when pressed the button menu changes from display none to display block and I want to make #account-info-main background would have backdrop-filter: blur(20px); but for me it doesn`t appear. https://ibb.co/FnNWYMB

HTML:

```
<div class="account">
 <button class="profile-dropdown" id="profilie-dropdown-id" onclick="show_list_profile()">
  <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
 </button>                        
 <div id="account-info-main">
   <div class="account-info">
    Other code
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .account {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    
  }

  .profile-dropdown:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .profile-dropdown {
    color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #ff8906;
    background-color: #0000007c;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .account-info {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }


  #account-info-main {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-70%);
    margin-top: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 400px;
    display: none;
    border: 3px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.507);
    backdrop-filter:  blur(20px);

  }
```

JS:

```
      function show_list_profile() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("account-info-main");
    
        if (dropdown.style.display == "block") {
            dropdown.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdown.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the `backdrop-filter: blur(20px);` in your code. Did you forget to include your JS code in the question? Especially your `show_list_profile` method

Comment: @indyteo i writed that i want backdrop blur be in #account-info-main, about the js code i will edit the question

Comment: As per @indyteo - `backdrop-filter:  blur(20px);` should be in the CSS for `#account-info-main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was of nested other elements who had backdrop-filter: blur, solution found in [backdrop-filter not working for nested elements in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997948/backdrop-filter-not-working-for-nested-elements-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the `backdrop-filter: blur(20px)` on some background element, between your content and your dropdown menu. Example:

```js
function show_list_profile() {
  let dropdown = document.getElementById("account-info-main");
  let background = document.getElementById("background");

  if (dropdown.style.display == "block") {
    dropdown.style.display = "none";
    background.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dropdown.style.display = "block";
    background.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.account {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-dropdown:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.profile-dropdown {
  color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ff8906;
  background-color: #0000007c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.account-info {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#account-info-main {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-70%);
  margin-top: 1%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  display: none;
  border: 3px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
  background-color: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.507);
  z-index: 2;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="account">
    <button class="profile-dropdown" id="profilie-dropdown-id" onclick="show_list_profile()">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="account-info-main">
      <div class="account-info">
        Other code
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="background" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

Breakdown:

- I wrapped the HTML into a `#parent` div to allow the background to spread the whole page. This is not strictly necessary, you may want to remove it so the backdrop cover the whole page OR only this parent div, depending on your needs.
- I added a `#background` div hidden by default, which create the backdrop effect behind the dropdown. It has a the backdrop CSS, and also `pointer-events: none;` to allow clicks to pass through it. Its visibility gets toggled the same way as the dropdown is. It has a `z-index: 1;`.
- I gave `z-index: 2;` to the dropdown (`#account-info-main`) to allow it to be above the background and the blur effect.

Comment: I want that the menu background be with backdrop filter, not the under the menu.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you can share a picture describing your expectation and we'll be able to help to coding it?

Comment: how to add pic?

Comment: Upload it on an external picture sharing website like [imgur](https://imgur.com/upload) then send the link

Comment: https://ibb.co/FnNWYMB