# before pseudo element came in front of div when using backdrop filter

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am trying to create master card and i want a vertical line behind it. When i use backdrop filter on master card it works fine. But when i put it on its parent element ::before pseudo element come in front of master card. I can't even fix this with z-index.

I tried this on firefox but i have to add backdrop-filter to both parent and child then this works

Here's the code:-

```css
:root {
        --white: #fff;
        --gold: rgb(255, 215, 0);
        --bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
      }
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
          ),
          url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/460635/pexels-photo-460635.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .container {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        width: 50%;
        height:90vh;
        margin:2rem;
        padding: 5rem;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px var(--gold), 0px 0px 3px var(--gold);
        border: 0.1rem solid var(--gold);
        border-radius: 3rem;
        position: relative;
        backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);
        &::before {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 50%;
          translate: -50% 0%;
          width: 0.2rem;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: var(--gold);
        }
        .master-card {
          text-transform: capitalize;
          color: var(--white);
          width: 100%;
          aspect-ratio: 2/1;
          /*backdrop-filter: blur(1rem);*/
          background-color: var(--bg-color);
          border: none;
          border-radius: inherit;
          padding: 2.5rem;
          box-shadow: inherit;

          display: flex;
          & .brand-bg {
            width: 10%;
            aspect-ratio: 1;
            border-radius: 50%;
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Master card</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="master-card">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="brand">
            <span class="brand-bg"></span><span class="brand-bg"></span>
            <h2>master card</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <p>card number</p>
            <p>8050 5040 2030 3020</p>
          </div>
          <p>prem kumar shahi</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think should use a hr tag then rotate it but because of padding it could touch the borders of the container div.

Here's an image of the design. "This image is from firefox since its somehow working on it"

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of the design?

Comment: @SyndRain if the increase master-card opacity by .1 and complete the whole design then i would be very less noticeable since the glassy effect

Comment: The code works as expected, like the other comment said that opacity level was the key, you can created another vertical line in the pink box and align it with the line in the outer box and set backdrop filter for that only, but i guess just keep what you have is easier, backdrop twice.

Comment: @Stickers Yeah I thought its working as expect.  However, when I make the line behind the `master-card` using `z-index`,  the backdrop filter on `master-card` looks very different (blurring the line way more significantly just like OP) on FF 123 compare to Chrome 122. I'm not sure what's the reason yet though.

Comment: I see what you mean @SyndRain just checked it on chrome, don't know why that happens

Comment: Looks like so, related https://stackoverflow.com/q/60997948

Comment: Yeah but I was not sure because the vertical line doesn't seem to be outside the parent backdrop root. Maybe there is something I'm misunderstanding about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Chromium and Edge bug that nested `backdrop-filter` blurring is not working correctly. (If the backdrop-filter on the parent is removed, the backdrop-filter on the child will work as expect.) Many similar issues have being [reported](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40942655) on Chromium.

The vertical line **should be blurred** since it is included in the [backdrop root image](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#backdrop-root-image) (backdrop-filter’s filter operations will applied to) as per [spec](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#backdrop-root-image):

> The Backdrop Root Image for an element E is the final image that would be produced by the following steps:
>
> 1. Start at the Backdrop Root element that is the nearest ancestor of E.
> 2. Paint all content, in painting order, between (and including) the ancestor Backdrop Root element and element E.

— Here, the Backdrop Root element of `master-card` is `container`, and the vertical line element is indeed between them.

One way achieve the effect is to apply the `backdrop-filter` on a sibling element of the child to blur the background. The example below uses `::after` with negative `z-index`, but you can also add another `div` if `::after` is being used as well.

```css
:root {
  --white: #fff;
  --gold: rgb(255, 215, 0);
  --bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/460635/pexels-photo-460635.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px var(--gold), 0px 0px 3px var(--gold);
  border: 0.1rem solid var(--gold);
  border-radius: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  }
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    translate: -50% 0%;
    width: 0.2rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--gold);
  }
  .master-card {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: var(--white);
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 2/1;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    border: none;
    border-radius: inherit;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    display: flex;
    & .brand-bg {
      width: 10%;
      aspect-ratio: 1;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="master-card">
      <div class="left-side">
        <div class="brand">
          <span class="brand-bg"></span><span class="brand-bg"></span>
          <h2>master card</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p>card number</p>
          <p>8050 5040 2030 3020</p>
        </div>
        <p>prem kumar shahi</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-side"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: but i want that vertical line inside the container div

Comment: Oh I've mis-seen. Let me fix it.